# Issues with firefox, localized storage, and dpkg

Tags: 14.04, firefox, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and this started after I restarted my computer. What happened originally was it wouldn't wake up so to speak after I left it idle, and logged out. It was just a black screen, which I had before, but I found a solution a while back. It was a power management thing, and it was fixed. Then I started to have some internet problems specific to only my computer. Websites would load slow, and I'd either have to refreshed one or more times, or close the tab then try again, but sometimes I'd have to disconnect then reconnect to my wifi. No one else in my house are having problems. I tried different things. One thing I tried was to turn off power management to my wireless adapter. It seemed like it helped, then another suggestion was to use WICD instead of the regular program that came with Ubuntu, but then after all of this my problems kept happening again.

I had to hard reset my computer when it wouldn't wake up, and when I went into Firefox, everything was in basic html format. I found out that it was adblock plus somehow causing the problem, and when I disable it, it goes back to normal. BEFORE all this I had to reinstall Firefox, because I got a message saying something was malformed. I tried to reinstall it a few minutes ago using the code

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install firefox
```

And of course after using the code

```
apt-get update
```

And everything with that looked normal

Then after I accepted the uninstall confirmation for Firefox, it put

```
dpkg: error processing package xul-ext-websites-integration (--remove):unable to securely remove '/usr/share/xul-ext/websites-integration/chrom/unity_webapps.jar': Not a directory Errors were encountered while processing:xul-ext-websites-integrationE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's own answer:

What I did was went into synaptics package manager, and just reinstalled xul-ext-websites-integreation from there, and it fixed it. I found out it was only half installed.